# Error: no match for 'operator>' (operand types are 'Student' and 'Student'

Tags: c++

I have a problem in bottom code(kontener.h, in function void List::push ), seems like a simple error but I am stuck for few hours now.
I have another header but didn't post it here because its irrelevent to the problem in my opinion (could be wrong)

MAIN.CPP

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdexcept>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include <fstream>
#include "student.h"
#include "kontener.h"
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    List < Student > S;

    fstream GRA("GRA.txt", ios::in);
    if (!GRA.good())
        throw logic_error("Nie znaleziono pliku GRA.TXT");
    fstream SID("SID.txt", ios::in);
    if (!SID.good())
        throw logic_error("Nie znaleziono pliku SID.TXT");

    while (!GRA.eof())
    {
        string nazwisko;
        string imie;
        string imie2;
        int index;
        int ocena;
        GRA >> nazwisko;
        GRA.ignore();
        GRA >> imie;
        ;
        GRA.ignore();
        GRA >> imie2;
        GRA.ignore();
        GRA >> index;
        GRA.ignore();
        GRA >> ocena;

        try
        {
            Student s1;
            s1.setNazwisko(nazwisko);
            s1.setImie(imie);
            s1.setImie2(imie2);
            s1.setIndex(index);
            s1.setOcena(ocena);
            S.push(s1);
        }
        catch (exception &e)
        {
            cout << e.what() << endl;
        }

    }

    GRA.close();
    SID.close();

    fstream INF("INF.TXT", ios::out);

    int counter = S.size();

    for (int i = 0; i < counter; i++)
    {
        Student s1 = S.pop();
        INF << s1.getIndex() << ";" << s1.getOcena() << ";" << s1.getNazwisko()
                << " " << s1.getImie() << "." << s1.getImie2();

    }

    INF.close();

}
```

Kontener.h (ERROR IS IN THIS FILE)
Error: no match for 'operator>' (operand types are 'Student' and 'Student'

```
#ifndef KONTENER_H_INCLUDED
#define KONTENER_H_INCLUDED
#include <iostream>
#include <stdexcept>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;

template<typename T>
struct List
{
private:
    struct Node
    {
        T value;
        Node *next;
        Node(T v, Node *n = nullptr)
        {
            value = v;
            next = n;
        }
    };
    Node *head;
    int counter;
public:
    List();

    ~List();

    T pop();

    void push(T x);

    int size() const;

};

template<typename T>
List<T>::List()
{
    head = nullptr;
    counter = 0;
}

template<typename T>
List<T>::~List()
{
    while (head != nullptr)
    {
        Node *killer = head;
        head = head->next;
        delete killer;
    }
    counter = 0;
}

template<typename T>
T List<T>::pop()
{
    if (counter != 0)
    {
        Node *killer = head;
        T x = killer->value;
        head = head->next;
        delete killer;
        counter--;
        return x;
    }
    else
        throw logic_error("Empty list.");
}

template<typename T>
int List<T>::size() const
{
    return counter;
}

template<typename T>
void List<T>::push(T x)
{
    Node *pred = nullptr;
    Node *succ = head;

    while (succ!=0 && succ->value > x)  // ERROR OCCURS HERE
    {   
        pred=succ;
        succ=succ->next;
    }

    Node *creator = new Node(x, succ);
    if (pred == nullptr)
    {
        head = creator;
    }
    else
    {
        pred->next = creator;
    }
    counter++;
}

#endif // KONTENER_H_INCLUDED
```

Comment: With `alice` and `bob`, two instances of `Student`, does `alice < bob` compile? I bet it doesn't. Fix it. While you're doing so, read [ask] and [mcve]. It'll help you for your next question.

Comment: Why are you doing `while (succ!=0 && succ->value > x)`?  Are you making a sorted list?  If so you should change the name of the class.

Comment: Verify that `Student` has `operator>` overloaded.  You may want to edit your post with the definition of `class Student`.

Comment: `while (!GRA.eof())` whyyyyyy :(

Answer (score 0):

`succ->value` and `x` are of type `Student`. You are trying to use an operator on these, specifically the operator `>`. Your compiler is telling you that there is no `operator>` defined for two values of type `Student`.

You need to implement the operator yourself.

The signature of such an operator looks like this:

```
inline bool operator> (const Student& s1, const Student& s2);
```

Or as member in the `Student` class itself:

```
inline bool operator> (const Student& other) const;
```

You can also search your project first to check if the operator is, in fact, implemented somewhere, and that you just didn't include the appropriate header.

Comment: Added this:


          bool operator>(Student&k)
         {
        return index > k.index;
    }
Fixed the error, thanks alot

Comment: @JacekSkowron Some helpful reading on operators: [What are the basic rules and idioms for operator overloading?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4421706/what-are-the-basic-rules-and-idioms-for-operator-overloading)